# Excel, customize Autofill feature

Tags: excel, autofill

Hi Stackoverflow Folks,
Im trying to do this simple task of reformating survey results:

What i have:
An excel sheet with a Table of 400+ rows and 10+ columns of survey information to a specific customer.

```
       A              B              C              D
1     ID          Question1       Question2      Question3
2     002            no             2015
3     003                           2013
4     004            yes
5     005                                          bad
```

What i want to accomplish:

```
       X              Y
1     002         Question1:no Question2: 2015
2     003         Question2:2015
3     004         Question1:yes
4     005         Question3:bad
```

What a tried so far in a normal Excel Formula is something like this:

```
=IF(B2="";"";(B1&B2))&" "&IF(C2="";"";(C1&C2))&" "&IF(D2="";"";(D1&D2))
```

and so on for a cellformula in "Y"

This works so far. Now i want to use the autofill pullfunction to pull down the formula on other cells further down and it fills my cells with formulas like this:

```
=IF(B3="";"";(B2&B3))&" "&IF(C3="";"";(C2&C3))&" "&IF(D3="";"";(D2&D3))
```

which is not what im looking for in this case, since i dont want the question to change, only the answer value to something like this

```
=IF(B3="";"";(B1&B3))&" "&IF(C3="";"";(C1&C3))&" "&IF(D3="";"";(D1&D3))
=IF(B4="";"";(B1&B4))&" "&IF(C4="";"";(C1&C4))&" "&IF(D4="";"";(D1&D4))
```

So the question is, how do i autofill by dragging down the cellformula without changing specific cellnumbers.
The manual way would be to change 400+ formulas which is a bad thing to do.

Thanks in advance for your help.

btw. i never used VBA Scripts and only would try to use a VBA Script if there is no other possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work?

```
=IF(B2="";"";(B$1&B2))&" "&IF(C2="";"";(C$1&C2))&" "&IF(D2="";"";(D$1&D2))
```

Comment: It locks cell references. So if you also put a $ before B, like $B$1 it would lock that cell reference no matter how you copy and paste vertically of horizontally. By only having one $ before the number "B$1" it means it will lock the row reference but not the column reference. So if you try to copy this to the right, you will notice the B changes to a C but if you copy down there is no change as 1 is locked with $